# Link to UNC/local resource in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, windows, unc

I want to link local [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Naming_Convention) path (windows network path) from my html. I tried many variations in anchor tag like,

```html
 1. <a href="\\\\somemachine\\path">link</a>
 2. <a href="file://\\somemachine\\path">link</a>
 3. <a href="file://///\\somemachine\\path">link</a>
 4. <a href="\\somemachine\path">link</a>
```

But, nothing seems working. I have chromium nightly build and also tried t on Firefox. Is there is any path combination that can work or if through javascript, it is possible?

Comment: Look at the following comment on firefox - makes sense to me to forbid this... http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work

Answer (score 1):

The correct URL schema to link against to local file system is

```
file://
```

after that, the rest of the UNC path follows. You must replace all backslashes by forward slashes and add one `/` to denote the file system root:

```
file://///somemachine/path
```

A shorter variant works in IE and Google Chrome:

```
file://somemachine/path
```

Comment: From browser's address bar it is working fine but not helping when accessing from anchor.

Comment: @Gagandeep: This (`<a href="file://///somemachine/path">`) works for me. Can you post the HTML you use? Also note that spaces and other special characters must be properly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
file://somemachine//path
```